# IIS application pool reset - Site performance impact

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, iis-8, application-pool, applicationpoolidentity

We have the following issue in our application hosted in IIS.

Our website performance is going drastically down when the **concurrent users hit count increased to 100s.** (Our application is hosted in the IIS version 8.5)

Server - Windows server 2008

IIS - 8.5

Application - ASP.NET MVC/Angular

DB - SQL server 2016

But the speed is resumed back when we restart the Application pool on which the application is running.
When the application performance is going down, the following attributes were observed and they look normal.

1) CPU usage - the max was at 70% when the peak load hits.

2) Memory usage - the server memory usage was not more that 40%

3) Checked if there any deadlocks in the DB and looked normal

4) Verified the code and connections were properly handled using 'using statement'

Please let me know what exactly could causing the slowness when the load increase and why its addressed while restarting the app pool.

I know for this scenario, I cant give code sample and need immediate guidance from the experts. Please let me know if you need more details to help.

Thank you!!!

Comment: "when the concurrent users hit count increased to 100s"? How can "100s" be hit count"? Generally speaking, no performance analysis can go beyond the general steps, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2006/10/16/net-hang-debugging-walkthrough/ but if you are not capable of analyzing at that level, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: How intensive are the calls you are making asynchronously? Are there opportunities for locking to occur on threads? This seems like there could be a lot of thread waiting and deadlocking because of the sheer number of attempts to access a small set of tables? If so, how are you storing session information? Is anything able to be put into a cache or a session to limit the calls to the database?

Comment: Thanks for the commensts. Our application is SPA architecture and all the API calls made Asyncronously from the Js file. Also, we use connection pooling properly and all our DB queries has 'using' statement.